# Review answers before submitting the Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to echo the answers before the form is submitted so the user can check them, but I couldn't find any way of doing it through a script or app.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Forms, there is no built-in or Google Apps Script way to echo the answers before form submission.

One alternative is to create a custom form by using Google Apps Script.

Comment: Can you share how to create a custom form? @Rubén

Answer (score 0):

Do like StackOverflow does it. Use the keystroke up event to fill an input or label with the values. On every event check for inputs that are filled and concatenate  them in a pleasantly viewable way.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped in thinking simple web forms with HTML inputs. Might not be possible with Google Forms.